# Understanding implicit in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, playframework, keyword

I was making my way through the Scala playframework tutorial and I came across this snippet of code which had me puzzled:

```
def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
        label => {
          Task.create(label)
          Redirect(routes.Application.tasks())
        } 
  )
}
```

So I decided to investigate and came across [this post](http://pietrowski.info/2009/07/scala-implicit-conversion/).

I still don't get it.

What is the difference between this:

```
implicit def double2Int(d : Double) : Int = d.toInt
```

and

```
def double2IntNonImplicit(d : Double) : Int = d.toInt
```

other than the obvious fact they have different method names.

When should I use `implicit` and why?

Comment: Found this tutorial really useful: [Scala Tutorial - Learn How To Create Implicit Function](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-3-beginner-tutorial-using-functions-scala/scala-tutorial-learn-create-implicit-function/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458954/how-to-write-an-implicit-numeric-for-a-tuple

Answer (score 441, accepted):

I'll explain the main use cases of implicits below, but for more detail see the [relevant chapter of Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html).

**Implicit parameters**

The final parameter list on a method can be marked `implicit`, which means the values will be taken from the context in which they are called. If there is no implicit value of the right type in scope, it will not compile. Since the implicit value must resolve to a single value and to avoid clashes, it's a good idea to make the type specific to its purpose, e.g. don't require your methods to find an implicit `Int`!

example:

```
  // probably in a library
class Prefixer(val prefix: String)
def addPrefix(s: String)(implicit p: Prefixer) = p.prefix + s

  // then probably in your application
implicit val myImplicitPrefixer = new Prefixer("***")
addPrefix("abc")  // returns "***abc"
```

**Implicit conversions**

When the compiler finds an expression of the wrong type for the context, it will look for an implicit `Function` value of a type that will allow it to typecheck. So if an `A` is required and it finds a `B`, it will look for an implicit value of type `B => A` in scope (it also checks some other places like in the `B` and `A` companion objects, if they exist). Since `def`s can be "eta-expanded" into `Function` objects, an `implicit def xyz(arg: B): A` will do as well.

So the difference between your methods is that the one marked `implicit` will be inserted for you by the compiler when a `Double` is found but an `Int` is required.

```
implicit def doubleToInt(d: Double) = d.toInt
val x: Int = 42.0
```

will work the same as

```
def doubleToInt(d: Double) = d.toInt
val x: Int = doubleToInt(42.0)
```

In the second we've inserted the conversion manually; in the first the compiler did the same automatically. The conversion is required because of the type annotation on the left hand side.

---

Regarding your first snippet from Play:

Actions are explained on [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActions) from the Play documentation (see also [API docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Action$.html)). You are using

```
apply(block: (Request[AnyContent]) ⇒ Result): Action[AnyContent]
```

on the `Action` object (which is the companion to the trait of the same name).

So we need to supply a Function as the argument, which can be written as a literal in the form

```
request => ...
```

In a function literal, the part before the `=>` is a value declaration, and can be marked `implicit` if you want, just like in any other `val` declaration. Here, `request` *doesn't* have to be marked `implicit` for this to type check, but by doing so it will be *available as an implicit value* for any methods that might need it within the function (and of course, it can be used explicitly as well). In this particular case, this has been done because the `bindFromRequest` method on the [Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.6/api/scala/play/api/data/Form.html) class requires an implicit `Request` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The link for chapter 21 is really awesome. Appreciate it.

Comment: Just to add this, following video gives excellent explanation of implicits plus some other features of scala http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IobLWVuD-CQ

Comment: Jump to *24:25* in the video above (for those that don't want to listen through the 55 mins)

Answer (score 50):

**WARNING:** contains sarcasm judiciously! YMMV...

[Luigi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375941/244935) is complete and correct. This one is only to extend it a bit with an example of how you can gloriously overuse *implicits*, as it happens quite often in Scala projects. Actually so often, you can probably even find it in one of the *"Best Practice"* guides.

```
object HelloWorld {
  case class Text(content: String)
  case class Prefix(text: String)

  implicit def String2Text(content: String)(implicit prefix: Prefix) = {
    Text(prefix.text + " " + content)
  }

  def printText(text: Text): Unit = {
    println(text.content)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    printText("World!")
  }

  // Best to hide this line somewhere below a pile of completely unrelated code.
  // Better yet, import its package from another distant place.
  implicit val prefixLOL = Prefix("Hello")
}
```

Comment: Haha. Good sense of humor.

Comment: I appreciate the humor.  This kind of thing is one of the reasons I stopped trying to learn Scala many years ago and am only now coming back to it.  I was never sure where some (many) of the implicits were coming from in the code I was looking at.

Answer (score 47):

**In scala implicit works as**:

*Converter*

*Parameter value injector*

*Extension method*

**There are some uses of Implicit**

1. **Implicitly type conversion** : It converts the error producing assignment into intended type

   ```
   val x :String = "1"

   val y:Int = x
   ```

**String** is not the **sub type of Int** , so error happens in line 2. To resolve the error the compiler will look for such a method in the scope which has implicit keyword and takes a **String** as argument and returns an **Int** .

so

```
implicit def z(a:String):Int = 2

val x :String = "1"

val y:Int = x // compiler will use z here like val y:Int=z(x)

println(y) // result 2  & no error!
```

2. **Implicitly receiver conversion**: We generally by receiver call object's properties, eg. methods or variables . So to call any property by a receiver the property must be the member of that receiver's class/object.

   ```
    class Mahadi{

    val haveCar:String ="BMW"

    }
   ```

---

```
    class Johnny{

    val haveTv:String = "Sony"

    }
```

---

```
   val mahadi = new Mahadi



   mahadi.haveTv // Error happening
```

Here **mahadi.haveTv** will produce an error. Because scala compiler will first look for the **haveTv** property to **mahadi** receiver. It will not find. Second it will look for a method in scope having **implicit keyword** which take **Mahadi object** as argument and returns **Johnny object**. But it does not have here. So it will create **error**. But the following is okay.

```
class Mahadi{

val haveCar:String ="BMW"

}
```

---

```
class Johnny{

val haveTv:String = "Sony"

}
```

---

```
val mahadi = new Mahadi

implicit def z(a:Mahadi):Johnny = new Johnny

mahadi.haveTv // compiler will use z here like new Johnny().haveTv

println(mahadi.haveTv)// result Sony & no error
```

3. **Implicitly parameter injection**: If we call a method and do not pass its parameter value, it will cause an error. The scala compiler works like this - first will try to pass value, but it will get no direct value for the parameter.

   ```
    def x(a:Int)= a

    x // ERROR happening
   ```

Second if the parameter has any implicit keyword it will look for any **val** in the **scope** which have the **same type** of value. If not get it will cause error.

```
def x(implicit a:Int)= a

x // error happening here
```

To slove this problem compiler will look for a **implicit val** having the **type of Int** because the parameter **a** has **implicit keyword**.

```
def x(implicit a:Int)=a

implicit val z:Int =10

x // compiler will use implicit like this x(z)
println(x) // will result 10 & no error.
```

**Another example:**

```
def l(implicit b:Int)

def x(implicit a:Int)= l(a)
```

we can also write it like-

```
def x(implicit a:Int)= l
```

Because **l** has a **implicit parameter** and in scope of **method x's body**, there is an **implicit local variable**(*parameters are local variables*) **a** which is the parameter of **x**, so in the **body of x** **method** the method-signature **l's implicit argument value** is filed by the **x method's local implicit variable(parameter) `a` implicitly**.

So

```
 def x(implicit a:Int)= l
```

will be in compiler like this

```
def x(implicit a:Int)= l(a)
```

**Another example:**

```
def c(implicit k:Int):String = k.toString

def x(a:Int => String):String =a

x{
x => c
}
```

it will cause error, because **c** in **x{x=>c}** needs explicitly-value-passing in argument or implicit val **in scope**.

So we can make the function literal's **parameter** explicitly **implicit** when we call the **method x**

```
x{
implicit x => c // the compiler will set the parameter of c like this c(x)
}
```

This has been used in **action method** of Play-Framework

```
in view folder of app the template is declared like
@()(implicit requestHreader:RequestHeader)

in controller action is like

def index = Action{
implicit request =>

Ok(views.html.formpage())  

}
```

if you do not mention request parameter as implicit explicitly then you must have been written-

```
def index = Action{
request =>

Ok(views.html.formpage()(request))  

}
```

4. **Extension Method**

Think, we want to add new method with Integer object. The name of the method will be meterToCm,

```
> 1 .meterToCm 
res0 100
```

to do this we need to create an implicit class within a object/class/trait . This class can not be a case class.

```
object Extensions{
    
    implicit class MeterToCm(meter:Int){
        
        def  meterToCm={
             meter*100
        }

    }

}
```

Note the **implicit class** will only take **one constructor parameter**.

Now import the implicit class in the scope you are wanting to use

```
import  Extensions._

2.meterToCm // result 200
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. really helpful +1

Comment: very helpful explanation for implicit usage in scala

Answer (score 7):

Why and when you should mark the `request` parameter as `implicit`:

Some methods that you will make use of in the body of your action have an **implicit parameter list** like, for example, Form.scala defines a method:

```
def bindFromRequest()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[_]): Form[T] = { ... }
```

You don't necessarily notice this as you would just call `myForm.bindFromRequest()` You don't have to provide the implicit arguments explicitly. No, you leave *the compiler* to look for any valid candidate object to pass in every time it comes across a method call that requires an instance of the request. Since you *do* have a request available, all you need to do is to mark it as `implicit`.

You *explicitly* mark it as available for *implicit* use.

You hint the compiler that it's "OK" to use the request object sent in by the Play framework (that we gave the name "request" but could have used just "r" or "req") wherever required, "on the sly".

```
myForm.bindFromRequest()
```

see it? it's not there, but it *is* there!

It just happens without your having to slot it in manually in every place it's needed (but you *can* pass it explicitly, if you so wish, no matter if it's marked `implicit` or not):

```
myForm.bindFromRequest()(request)
```

Without marking it as implicit, you would **have to** do the above. Marking it as implicit you don't have to.

**When** should you mark the request as `implicit`? You only really need to if you are making use of methods that declare an *implicit parameter list expecting an instance of the Request*. But to keep it simple, you could just get into the habit of marking the request `implicit` **always**. That way you can just write beautiful terse code.

Comment: "That way you can just write beautiful terse code."  Or, as @DanielDinnyes points out, beautifully obfuscated code.  It can be a real pain to track down where an implicit is coming from and they can actually make the code harder to read and maintain if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 5):

Also, in the above case there should be `only one` implicit function whose type is `double => Int`. Otherwise, the compiler gets confused and won't compile properly.

```
//this won't compile

implicit def doubleToInt(d: Double) = d.toInt
implicit def doubleToIntSecond(d: Double) = d.toInt
val x: Int = 42.0
```

Answer (score 3):

A very basic example of Implicits in scala.

**Implicit parameters**:

```
val value = 10
implicit val multiplier = 3
def multiply(implicit by: Int) = value * by
val result = multiply // implicit parameter wiil be passed here
println(result) // It will print 30 as a result
```

**Note:** Here `multiplier` will be implicitly passed into the function `multiply`. Missing parameters to the function call are looked up by type in the current scope meaning that code will not compile if there is no implicit variable of type Int in the scope.

**Implicit conversions**:

```
implicit def convert(a: Double): Int = a.toInt
val res = multiply(2.0) // Type conversions with implicit functions
println(res)  // It will print 20 as a result
```

**Note:** When we call `multiply` function passing a double value, the compiler will try to find the conversion implicit function in the current scope, which converts `Int` to `Double` (As function `multiply` accept `Int` parameter). If there is no implicit `convert` function then the compiler will not compile the code.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same question as you had and I think I should share how I started to understand it by a few really simple examples (note that it only covers the common use cases).

There are two common use cases in Scala using `implicit`.

- Using it on a variable
- Using it on a function

Examples are as follows

**Using it on a variable**. As you can see, if the `implicit` keyword is used in the last parameter list, then the closest variable will be used.

```
// Here I define a class and initiated an instance of this class
case class Person(val name: String)
val charles: Person = Person("Charles")

// Here I define a function
def greeting(words: String)(implicit person: Person) = person match {
  case Person(name: String) if name != "" => s"$name, $words"
    case _ => "$words"
}

greeting("Good morning") // Charles, Good moring

val charles: Person = Person("")
greeting("Good morning") // Good moring
```

**Using it on a function**. As you can see, if the `implicit` is used on the function, then the closest type conversion method will be used.

```
val num = 10 // num: Int (of course)

// Here I define a implicit function
implicit def intToString(num: Int) = s"$num -- I am a String now!"

val num = 10 // num: Int (of course). Nothing happens yet.. Compiler believes you want 10 to be an Int

// Util...
val num: String = 10 // Compiler trust you first, and it thinks you have `implicitly` told it that you had a way to covert the type from Int to String, which the function `intToString` can do!
// So num is now actually "10 -- I am a String now!"
// console will print this -> val num: String = 10 -- I am a String now!
```

Hope this can help.