# Converters for custom data types in Play?

Tags: java, playframework

Is there a predefined concept for converters or something similar in Play 2.0? (Having used JSF in the past, there is `javax.faces.convert.Converter` for converting specific types to String values and back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about Play 2.x, as the templates use Scala, in theory you could use Scala implicits to do automatic conversions between required types.

Be aware that it may cause some problems, better use it sparingly and only if completely necessary, but if it is justified...

Comment: Thank you Pere, could you give me a small snippet example? I'm not yet into Scala at all, currently.

Comment: @qqilihq this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala has information that will help you