# i18n, Messages object in every template necessary? Play Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, message

I am new to Play and Scala as well. And I meet a problem with i18n while reading book "*Play with Scala*". The problem was the `Messages` object, which has to be obtained in every template to let application work properly.

What bothers me is that even if I don't use the `Messages` object in one of my Scala template files, but I inherit/call another template in it, I still have to add 
`(implicit messages: Messages)` at the top of the file.

Can somebody explain me why is that? Is it necessary to add the `Messages` object in every template? Its quite problematic and I am sure it can be solved somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Play Framework specific problem, it is just how implicit parameters work in Scala (see [Understanding implicit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala)).

Take the following function which "magically" adds a number to a list of numbers.

```
def addMagic[A](numbers: List[Int])(implicit add: Int) = numbers.map(_ + add)
```

We can use `addMagic` as follows :

```
{
  implicit val magicNumber = 42
  addMagic(List(1, 2, 3))
  // List[Int] = List(43, 44, 45)
}
```

If we use `addMagic` in another function without passing an implicit `Int` :

```
def printMagicNumbers(numbers: List[Int]) = println(addMagic(numbers))
```

we get the following error:

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter add: Int

So we also need to add an implicit parameter to `printMagicNumbers` :

```
def printMagicNumbers(numbers: List[Int])(implicit add: Int) = 
  println(addMagic(numbers))
```

In the same manner your template function needs an implicit `Messages` object if it calls a template function which needs the `Messages` object.