# What does using "implicit request" mean in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework

My Scala level is a beginner and I saw an action method clearly demonstrating a declaration `implicit request=>`.   And my question is under what types of situation should we declare clearly?  I also have seen methods which don't declare `implicit request=>` or `request=>`.
Could anyone explain the advantage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will not cover the meaning of `implicit` in scala itself as it has already been answered on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala?rq=1). The play documentation also explains the use of `request =>` [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions) but does not give examples of a useful implicit request.

**TL; DR :** when in doubt, use `implicit request` as it may be needed by some components.

### Action without request

If the `request` does not change the result your block of code will return, it can be omitted and you can write.

```
def myAction = Action { Ok("Hello World") }
```

### With Request

If on the other hand you need to use the content of the request (header or body), then you have to add a `request` parameter. A common example of this is parsing the body of the request :

```
Action(parse.json) { request => // it works without implicit
  request.body.validate[MyClass].fold(/* do something */)
}
```

### With implicit request

The play documentation encourages us to mark the request parameter as `implicit` because even if you do not use the request directly, one component you use may need it as an implicit. If you ever get a missing implicit error in one of your action, it probably boils down to the fact that you forgot to make your request implicit.

I think a good example you might encounter in play is the [internationalization API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N). To sum up, it allows to automatically inject localized messages in your templates depending on the `Accept-Language` header in the request. All you have to do is add the `I18nSupport` trait to your controller and inject a `messagesApi: MessagesApi` parameter (and obviously define your internationalized messages). Then, in your twirl template, you can use the localized messages. For instance :

Template :

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages)
@* 
 message will be in english, spanish, klingon... depending on the supported 
 languages and request Accept-Language header
*@
@messages("say-hello")
```

Controller :

```
class MyController @Inject() (val messageApi: MessageApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
  def myAction = Action {implicit request => 
    // We do not have to bother about how messages are injected
    // The I18nSupport trait does the work for us
    Ok(html.myTemplate()) 
  }
 }
```

To be able to do this, the `I18nSupport` trait contains a def :

```
implicit def request2Messages(implicit request: RequestHeader): Messages = /* ... */
```

It allows to get an instance of `Messages` automatically (the compiler will implicitly call `request2Messages(yourRequest)` when needed but you need to have an implicit request (or request header) in scope.

Another example I have seen is automatically getting a user instance in the scope of the action when using some security frameworks in play.

### Side note

A annoying gotcha with this kind of implicit chain is that if you forget to make your request implicit, the compiler will probably complain about a missing implicit `Messages` in scope while the real problem is a missing implicit request.

Comment: Although this is a tiny question, is `Message` an instance? If so, `messages("say-hello")` is quite strange because it appears `"say-hello"` seems to be the argument.  And in your example, the template has to receive `Message` instance, so I think you should write like this: `Ok(html.myTemplate(messages))` where `messages` is the instance of `Message`.  Could you add more detailed explanation about it?  I know these are basic things, sorry.

Comment: Scala allows you to write myInstance(myParam) as long as your object defines a `apply` method so `messages("say-hello")` is just a shorthand for `messages.apply("say-hello")`. The omission of the `messages` argument in Ok(html.myTemplate()) is intentional. This is the whole point of using an implicit parameter. The compiler guess the `messages` argument from the context. [Jacob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41790056/2935481) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala?rq=1)  might help you understand the concept of implicit in scala.

Answer (score 2):

`implicit` in Scala has many use cases - one of them being passing parameters implicitly to functions that define implicit parameters.

For example:

```
def withImplicitParameter(greeting: String)(implicit name: String): Unit = {
  println(greeting + " " + name)
}

// Using implicits
implicit val name = "Bob"
withImplicitParameter("Hello") // "Bob" is passed in implicitly for name parameter. Prints "Hello Bob"
withImplicitParameter("Bye")("Joe") // "Joe" is passed in explicitly for name parameter. Prints "Bye Joe"
```

Therefore unless one of the functions you're calling has an implicit parameter of the type `Request` you don't need `{ implicit request => ... }`

More info can be found in [Scala's official documentation on implicit parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html)

Comment: Just as a side note, never use basic types as implicits. Wrap them in case classes.

Comment: @Reactormonk So, isn't the answer appropriate because he uses the basic type as an implicit?

Comment: It's merely a simple example of how implicit parameters work in Scala. The main point of my answer is unless you are calling a function that requires an implicit `Request`, there's no need to mark your request object as implicit

Answer (score 1):

Another example with similar API to play's `implicit req => ...`

```
case class ClassName(name: String)

def log(msg: String)(implicit className: ClassName) =
  System.out.println(s"message=`$msg` className=`${className.name}`")

val cls = Option(ClassName("ImplicitClass"))

cls.foreach { implicit name =>
  log("explicit message")
}
```

Produces

```
message=`explicit message` className=`ImplicitClass`
```