# How do implicit work in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a sample Spark code, which converts the `Seq` to the `Dataset`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val s = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
val ds = s.toDS()
```

The Scala `Seq` does not have the `toDS` method, it comes from Spark implicits. How is the Dataset created here?

Edit: I did look at other SO answers but could not see an example, which would explain how the implicit could be used in `s.toDS`. I've referenced to the sample answer in the comment.

Comment: @user8371915 I did see that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375941/328989 but didn't notice there a mention of `s.applyPrefix`, only `applyPrefix(s)`, which was not clear to me whether it could cover this case here `s.toDS`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala has a way to add methods to existing classes, like extension method in Kotlin (and C# as I remember), but does it in a different way, through implicits.

To add the method to existing class, you first create implicit class:

```
object StringImplicits {
  implicit class StringUtils(s: String) {
    def someCoolMethod = println("Yooo")
  }
}

object Application extends App {
    import StringImplicits._
    val s = "Hello"
    s.someCoolMethod
}
```

You import this `StringUtils` and can call `someCoolMethod` on instance of `String`

Notice that `StringUtils` class takes `String` as a constuctor param.

When calling some method on `String`, scala compiler first looks this method in `String` class.

If it does not find it, it will look imported implicit classes which take `String` param.

If found, it calls the method from that class.

If no such class found, it will raise the error.