# What are the uses of implicits and How to use them in scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

The `implicit` keyword is a very obscure thing to programmers who come from Java and other languages like `C` and `C++`, so knowing about the `implicit` keyword in Scala is very important. How is `implicit` used in Scala?

> Many may find it a duplicate of other post but it is not that. It is
>   different.

Edit ::

Most of the times the question "**What is the usage of implicits in Scala?**" is answered in the sense of things like "**how to write/use implicit conversions?**", "**how to use implicit type classes?**" and so on.

For new Scala programmers (at least those I know), such answers most of the time put forward the impression that `implicits` are actually just a "beautifying" tool to cut down things like,

```
val s = (new RichInt(5)).toString + ":: Well"
```

to just

```
val s = 5 + ":: Well"
```

And most of just treat implicit as nothing more than this shortening tool which they can always avoid if desired.

Some of the programmers with more "bare-metal" philosophy tend to even dislike the existence of `implicit` which hides such details.

Somehow the important question which is "**What is the "use and importance" of `implicits` in Scala?**" has somehow gone ignored and unanswered.

Specially programmers who know Scala enough to understand "how to use `implicits`" to some extent and are sometimes trouble by the "hidden magic" wonder about the question - "**What is so special about implicits that the Scala creators even choose to have `implicits`?**"

I am not very sure whether the OP also thought about these questions while exploring the `implicits` as a Scala programmer.

And surprisingly, I have not found answers to these questions anywhere easily accessible. One reason is that answering even one of the use cases for the actual "need/benefits" of `implicits` will require a lot of explanation.

I think these questions are worth the focus of community for helping the new Scala programmers. I have tried to simply explain one of the use cases for the `implicits`. I hope to see more people (who are more knowledgeable) interested in answering this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding implicit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala)

Comment: @Mahadia Hossain - it seems this (Q&A) would work better as a blog post

Comment: @ygor No, it is  about how implicit is used in scala. This will be helpful for other how want to know the using way of implicit.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in order to answer them yourself. Especially when it is a poor answer...

Comment: @Tim In this case I agree it was a bad idea, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: @Tim,  I know it is poor answer but it covers all the areas of implicit. If you visit any forum of scala you will find implicit is a horror to all other language programmers. I don't know why you are reacting and down voted it. If there is any problem in my answer, I will request you to know me the problem prevailing here in answer, This will help me also to learn. I will appreciate.

Comment: @Tim, this is the first time I have heard about genuine question. If I know something and stackoverflow let me share my knowing to help other, what is the problem?? I in this case with due respect request you to help me showing my problems. This would rather help others to know the correct thing.

Comment: @Md.MahadiaHossain If you have a specific problem with `implicit` in your code, then post it here and we will help. If you want general information about how to program in Scala, this is not the right place.

Comment: @Tim, plz read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Md.MahadiaHossain It says "If you have a question that you already know the answer to ..." but by your own admission you don't have an answer to this question.

Comment: @Tim, it says: "you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."

Comment: There is documentation on [scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/) that explains [implicit parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html), [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) and [implicit classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html). If you have a problem with a particular use of `implicit`, or a problem with `implicit` in your code, then please do ask a specific question on this site.

Comment: @Md.MahadiaHossain that applies to good and on-topic questions. It doesn't apply to off-topic questions like this one.

Comment: @jwvh I have added some more context to the question. And have started a reopen vote. Can you guys take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am answering this question more from the perspective of "*what are the uses of `implicits` (why are `implicit` required in some situations)*" instead of *"how to use `implicit` in some of these situations"* (as answer to this can be found by searching on google).
>
> While explaining, I somehow ended up using `type` and `class` in an interchangeable way at some places. It should still convey the intended information in a simple way but it may indicate to the mis-conception that `type` and `class` are similar. I don't see a way to fix that without doing heavy changes in the answer. Just keep in mind that `type` and `class` are not same things.

**What `implicit` actually does.**

It is actually very simple, `implicit` does exactly what the name implies. It marks things as a "go to" instance/value in the corresponding scope, if there is ever a need to look for the "go to" instance of the said type.

So we can say that an `implicit` instance/value of type `A` is the "go to" instance of type `A` whenever there is a need for a "go to" instance of type `A`.

To mark any instance/value as `implicitly` ("go to") available in corresponding scope, we need to use `implicit` keyword.

```
scala> implicit val i: Int = 5
// i: Int = 5
```

**How do we summon `implicit` instances/values when needed?**

Most direct way to summon an `implicit` is to use `implictly` method.

```
val gotoInt = implicitly[Int]
// gotoInt: Int = 5
```

Or we can define our `methods` with `implicit` parameters to expect the availability of an `implicit` instance in the scope they are being used in,

```
def addWithImplictInt(i: Int)(implicit j: Int): Int = i + j
```

Keep in mind that we could have also defined the same method without specifying `implicit` parameter,

```
def addWithImplicitInt(i: Int): Int = {
  val implictInt = implicitly[Int]
  i + implictInt
}
```

Notice that the first choice with `implicit` parameter makes it clear to the user that the `method` expects implicit parameter. Because of this reason, the `implicit` parameter should be the choice in most cases (exceptions are always there).

**Why do we actually use `implicit`?**

This is a bit different from possible ways in which we can use `implicit` values. We are talking about why do we "actually" need to use them.

The answer is to help the compiler with ascertaining `type` and help us in writing type-safe code for problems which will otherwise result in run-time type comparisons and we end up loosing all the help which the compiler can provide us with.

Consider the following example,

Lets say we are using a library which has following types defined,

```
trait LibTrait

case class LibClass1(s: String) extends LibTrait
case class LibClass2(s: String) extends LibTrait
case class LibClass3(s: String) extends LibTrait
case class LibClass4(s: String) extends LibTrait
```

Considering that this is an open `trait`, you and anyone else can define their own classes to extend this `LibTrait`.

```
case class YourClass1(s: String) extends LibTrait
case class YourClass2(s: String) extends LibTrait

case class OthersClass1(s: String) extends LibTrait
case class OthersClass2(s: String) extends LibTrait
```

Now, we want to define a `method` which works with only some of the implementations of `LibTrait` (only those having some particular properties and thus can perform that special behaviour which you need).

```
// impl_1
def performMySpecialBehaviour[A <: LibTrait](a): Unit
```

But, the above will allow everything which extends `LibTrait`.

One choice is to define methods for all of the "supported" classes. But since you don't control the extension of `LibTrait`, you can not even do that (it is also not a very elegant choice).

Another choice is to model these "Restrictions" for your method,

```
trait MyRestriction[A <: LibTrait] {
  def myRestrictedBehaviour(a: A): Unit
}
```

Now, only subtypes of `LibTrait` supporting this particular behaviour will be able to come up with an implementation of `MyRestriction`.

Now, in most simple way, you define your method using this,

```
// impl_2 
def performMySpecialBehaviour(mr: MyRestriction): Unit
```

So, now users first have to convert their `instances` to some `implementation` of `MyRestriction` (which will ensure that your restrictions are met).

But looking at the signature of `performMySpecialBehaviour` you won't see any resemblance to what you actually wanted.

Also, it seems that your restriction are bound to `class` and not the instances themselves, so we can just progress with `type class` usage.

```
// impl_3
def performMySpecialBehaviour[A <: LibTrait](a: A, mr: MyRestriction[A]): Unit
```

Users can define type-class `instance` for their `class` and use your it with your `method`

```
object myRestrictionForYourClass1 extends MyRestriction[YourClass1] {
  def myRestrictedBehaviour(a: A): Unit = ???
}
```

But looking at the signature of `performMySpecialBehaviour` you won't see any resemblance to what you actually wanted.

But, if you were to use consider the use of `implicits`, we can bering more clarity to the usage

```
// impl_4
def performMySpecialBehaviour[A :< LibTrait](a: A)(implicit ev: MyRestriction[A]): Unit
```

**But I can still pass the type class instance as in impl_3. So why `implicit`?**

Yes, that is because the example problem is too simple. Lets add more to it.

Remember that the `LibTrait` is still open for extension. Lets consider you or someone in your team ended up having with following,

```
trait YoutTrait extends LibTrait

case class YourTraitClass1(s: String) extends YoutTrait
case class YourTraitClass2(s: String) extends YoutTrait
case class YourTraitClass3(s: String) extends YoutTrait
case class YourTraitClass4(s: String) extends YoutTrait
```

Notice that `YoutTrait` is also an open trait.

So, each of these will have their own corresponding instances for `MyRestriction`,

```
object myRestrictionForYourTraitClass1 extends MyRestriction[YourTraitClass1] {...}
object myRestrictionForYourTraitClass2 extends MyRestriction[YourTraitClass1] {...}
...
...
```

And you have this other method, which calls `performMySpecialBehaviour`

```
def otherMethod[A <: YoutTrait](a: A): Unit = {
  // do something before
  val mr: MyRestriction[A] = ??????????
  performMySpecialBehaviour(a, mr)
  // do something after
}
```

Now, how do you pick the `MyRestriction` instance to provide. The thing is, you can still do it in a round-about way by also providing a `Map` with `Class` as key and `MyRestriction` instance as value for all your `types`. But it is an ugly hack it won't be effective at compile time.

But if you use the `implict` based `impl_4`, your the same method will look like this,

```
def otherMethod[A <: YoutTrait](a: A)(implicit ev: MyRestriction[A]): Unit = {
  // do something before
  performMySpecialBehaviour(a)
  // do something after
}
```

And will work as long as the `MyRestriction` instances for all the subtypes for `YoutTrait` are in scope. Otherwise the code will fail to compile.

So, if someone adds a new subtype `YourTraitClassXX` of `YoutTrait` and forgets to ensure that the `MyRestriction[YourTraitClassXX]` instance is defined and is made available in the scope where any `otherMethod` calls are being made, the code will fail to compile.

This is just one example but it should suffice to show "why" and "what" are the actual uses of `implicits` in Scala

There is so much more to say about `implicits` but that will make the answer too long; which it already is.

The use case in this example, puts a bound on the parameter type `A` to have an instance of `type class` `TypeClass[A]` in scope. It is called `Context Bound` and such methods are in general written as,

```
def restricted[A, B](a: A)(implicit ev: TypeClass[A]): B
```

Or,

```
def restricted[A: TypeClass, B](a: A): B
```

> Note:: If you notice any problem with the answer, please comment. Any feedback is welcome.