# how to inline a minBy result

Tags: scala

I have the following scala code:

```
val test = rows.groupBy(l => l(8))
val m = test.reduce((a, b) => if (a._2.size > b._2.size) a else b)
val mina = m._2.minBy(x => x(0));
val minv = mina(0);
```

I would like to write

```
val minv = m._2.minBy(x => x(0))(0);
```

but I get a compiler error

```
[error] D:\dev\local\spark\httpLogs\src\main\scala\Main.scala:35:38: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(0)
[error]  required: Ordering[String]
[error]                                 val minv = m._2.minBy(x => x(0))(0);
[error]                                                                  ^
```

I also try

```
val minv = (m._2.minBy(x => x(0)))(0);
```

but just get another error.

Can this be written in one line ?

Comment: Does
`val minv = (m._2.minBy(x => x(0))).apply(0)`
work?

Comment: indeed, but I don't understand why `b = f(a)(0)` fails and `c = f(a);b = c(0)` succeed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala implicit parameters are neat, but if you don't know about them, they're confusing.

```
val mina = m._2.minBy(x => x(0))
```

is actually (resolved by implicit resolution)

```
val mina = m._2.minBy(x => x(0))(Ordering.String)
```

So when you're calling

```
val minv = m._2.minBy(x => x(0))(0)
```

You're actually passing the `0` as an explicit argument to the implicit.

By assigning the result to a variable, you're letting the compiler insert the implicit argument. If you're calling it directly, curried function arguments (the implicit is a curried argument after the explicit function) and syntax sugar for `apply` collide. And the compiler picks curried function arguments.

If you've got an object with an `apply` method on it, e.g. `List`:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
```

it'll rewrite that to `List.apply(1, 2, 3)`. That's why `apply` works in the above example, because it's telling the compiler to explicitly use the `apply`, instead of relying on the syntax sugar which gets overridden by the curried function.

More on implicits: [Understanding implicit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala)