# scala methods with variadic length of arguments

Tags: scala

I read a code of `finch`-library, and I see such examples

```
get("todos") {
    storeRef.get.map(m => Ok(m.values.toList.sortBy(-_.id)))
  }
```

or

```
delete("todos" :: path[Int]) { id: Int => ... }
```

I checked out these methods in my IDE, and these methods create a few objects [underhood](https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/io/finch/EndpointModule.scala#L190) (`Mappable`), but I still do not understand how it's possible. Because signatures of these methods do not contain any function as a parameter and moreover how they understand when param is Int or String or something else?

Comment: you are probably talking about implicits. check this answer for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375941/2096986

Comment: It seems they are using **Typeclasses**.